# How do change multiple specifc days in data frame

Tags: apache-spark, datetime, pyspark

I made a data frame from last year until present. I need to check sales for the 15 day from every month. But I don't know how to change all the dates from the data frame to ****-**-15 or to add ***exactly*** one months in the range.

Thank you so much for the help.

```
start= datetime.datetime.timestamp(datetime.datetime.strptime('2020-01-15', '%Y-%m-%d' ))
stop=datetime.datetime.timestamp(datetime.datetime.now())
datetimedataframe=spark.range(start, stop, 30*24*60*60).select(F.to_date(F.to_timestamp(F.col("id"))).alias("date"))

display(datetimedataframe)
```

```
datetimedataframe:
2020-01-15
2020-02-14
2020-03-15
2020-04-14
2020-05-14
2020-06-13
2020-07-13
2020-08-12
2020-09-11
2020-10-11
2020-11-10
2020-12-10
2021-01-09
2021-02-08
2021-03-10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can explode a sequence of dates, and union to the current date. Union ensures that the current date will not be repeated.

```
df = spark.sql("""
    select explode(sequence(date('2020-01-15'), date('2021-03-10'), interval 1 month)) as date 
    union 
    select current_date() as date 
    order by date
""")

df.show()
+----------+
|      date|
+----------+
|2020-01-15|
|2020-02-15|
|2020-03-15|
|2020-04-15|
|2020-05-15|
|2020-06-15|
|2020-07-15|
|2020-08-15|
|2020-09-15|
|2020-10-15|
|2020-11-15|
|2020-12-15|
|2021-01-15|
|2021-02-15|
|2021-03-10|
+----------+
```